# React-rails: Component with { prerender: true } issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-rails

I'm using the react-rails gem in a project.

Whenever I pass in the {prerender: true} in react_component helper, I am getting this error :

> Encountered error "ReferenceError: ReactDOMServer is not defined" when prerendering UsersList with

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same issue and haven't found a proper solution. I created an issue on the github repo of the gem. So far there's a workaround (for an other issue but it worked for me):

Copy/pasted from [issue #443](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails/issues/443#issuecomment-180544359)

1. Make sure components.js is compiled (`Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( components.js )`)
2. Add `//= require react-server` to your components.js file
3. Specify only components.js for server rendering:

   `config.react.server_renderer_options = {
     files: ["components.js"], # files to load for prerendering
   }`

UPDATE:

Downgrading the following gems: sprockets (2.12.4) and sprockets-rails (2.3.3) seems to avoid the issue.

Comment: which files did you change for #1 and #3 above?